# Problem with Boto3 AWS SES service "SignatureDoesNotMatch"

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-ses

I am a beginner in AWS SES Boto3 service

While Calling the send email service I am getting this error

**When calling the SendEmail operation: the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided, Check your AWS secret key and signing method**

I am using this version:

```
boto3==1.23.10
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the signature version:

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    }
)
```

Comment: he uses 'ses', not 's3'. Do you know the difference? The documentation for SES says nothing about `signature_version`. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html